# In a Bose-Einstein condensate, do the cooled particles lose weight?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, bose-einstein-condensate

Do particles in a laser trap interact differently with the gravitational field?

Comment: It is totally not clear what you are trying to ask. Perhaps, try to give a reference of what you are asking

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* user1785960! I've downvoted your question for the "it is not clear" reason. You might find the following link helpful: [How do I ask a good question?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I tried to clarify the question. Sorry for problems with my English.

Comment: As [this question's answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111328/) explain gravity is working for BECs.

Comment: @StephenG: Is BEC  have changed weight in relation to the weight before cooling?

Comment: I do not know what is unclear in my question. The answer is Yes. The leser change the energy state of electron to lower level. So energy is radiated -> atom mass is change. To lose more mass an atom should do not have electrons first then laser should trap core of this atom. However, I don't know if it would break the core of the atom. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is basically in the comments whether BEC changes weight relative to before cooling.

A BEC is formed by cooling a gas of extremely low density to ultra low temperatures.

AS the gas cooles (by laser), the energies of the molecules change via rotational and vibrational transitions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emission_spectrum

The answer is yes, because during the cooling, particles, molecules constantly lose rotational and vibrational energies (due to the laser cooling), and thus because of the energy mass equivalence, the gas will lose mass.

When the gas forms a BEC, it will still have mass, and stress-energy thus it will still interact gravitationally.

Comment: But this is not important. Typical experiments use alkali atoms that do not even have rotational degrees of freedom. Experimentally, the mass of the condensate will be indistinguishable from the sum of the atom masses. So the correct answer is: No, B-E condensation does not affect weight.

Comment: @Pieter are you suggesting that the laser cooling does not cause the atom/molecules to lose energy?

Comment: Ice is lighter than water but is one mole of ice lighter than one mole of water?

Comment: @Pieter well I was talking about all of the atoms in the gas/BEC. Why the downvote?

Comment: Because there is nothing special about the transition when it comes to weight. The molar weight is the same, at least it is not more different than how cooling something else affects its molar weight. Unmeasurable.

Comment: @Pieter he is asking "If the elementary particles are cooled, they lose a weight?" I answered that. You are talking about when the gas becomes BEC right? You are correct. Though, he is asking a more general question about cooling and I answered that.

Comment: Molar  is about particles cardinality. if weight of particles is changing then molar weight too.